# navigation is not working for @Hostlistener in angular 9

Tags: angular, iframe, authorize.net

I'm using `authorize.net` hosted form (iframe) and payments are getting success but
i'm not able to navigate from cureent page after recieving message via `@Hostlistener`.
Here is my code

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
  onMessage(event) {
   console.log(event)
     this.router.navigate(['/profile']); // Not working..?

    }
```

FYI: Navigation occurs olny after triggering reload manually

Comment: Does this: console.log(event) actually log something? Are you seeing any errors..?

Comment: im getting the event data. not any errors..